# Change date 'yyyy-MM-dd' into date 'dd-MM-yy' in Datatables data retrieved as JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datetime, datatables

I tried to do it with Datatables Ultimate date / time sorting plug-in
the data is retrieved as JSON and column 1 has value

eventdate":"2017-03-16T00:00:00.000Z"

```
       $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY' ); #as example

       $.fn.dataTable.moment = function ( format, locale ) {
            var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

            // Add type detection
            types.detect.unshift( function ( d ) {
                return moment( d, format, locale, true ).isValid() ?
                    'moment-'+format :
                    null;
            } );

            // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
            types.order[ 'moment-'+format+'-pre' ] = function ( d ) {
                return moment( d, format, locale, true ).unix();
            };
        };
```

But no effect whatsoever. Can anyone give me a hint? Tried also with deprecated date-euro and Columndefs[ {target: 0}] etc.. is this because it is retrieved as JSON? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What this question has to do with [tag:ruby] and [tag:ruby-on-rails]? Please remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: N.B. Just because the code *happens to be* inside a Rails app, that doesn't mean the tag is necessarily relevant. Your code above is **jQuery**, which you didn't even tag!

Comment: corrected! Has nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: You already have the date in the format that is sortable. Do you need to just display the date as dd-MM-yy?

Comment: Yes, I only need it to display as dd-MM-yyyy @Gyrocode.com